# NativeScript animated Modal Page

Tags: nativescript

I need Modal Page appears with "slide from bottom and cover (NOT push) current page" transition.
I set parameter `animated` of `showModal` method, but nothing changed.
How implement such transition for Modal Page? Android platform.

Comment: you can use css animation with translateY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's bug [github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5989](http://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5989)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have kinda hacky stuff, wrapping my elements with AbsoluteLayout and give it a high top value like '800',
and in navigatedTo function make transition animation with the negative value of the top attribute. In your case you would use left attribute and make transition over x.

Another solution that looks better in the UI, adding a custom component that would act as your modal, wrap your page elements with AbsoluteLayout, add your custom component when you need to show your modal, and apply the previous animation hack to it.

**Tip**: You can set the actionBarHiddin = true if you want to your custom component to overlay the full screen.

**Tip**: async/await and then would be very useful for the smoothing matters.